# Finding repeated state of the Queue (same elements in order) in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, queue

While solving some problem using C++ I used inbuilt Queue template to create a Queue. Now I need to check the state of the Queue after each operation on the Queue and report if the Queue happens to contain same elements (in same order) as in ANY one of the previous states of the Queue. For example, consider the following step-wise operations on the Queue (Left-hand-side represents the front and Right-hand-side represents rear/back of Queue):

1. (2, 4, 5, 1)
2. (4, 5, 1)
3. (4, 5, 1, 3)
4. (4, 5, 1, 3, 2)
5. (4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4)
6. (4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)
7. (5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)
8. (5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1)
9. (1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1)
10. (3, 2, 4, 5, 1)
11. (2, 4, 5, 1)

So the state of the Queue at step-11 is same (elements as well as order of elements) as in step-1. I need to find when this happens using C++. **I was thinking of using Map to store previous states of Queue**, but cannot figure out exactly how to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far exactly? A set seems more appropriate to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a different Container for this such as std::list since it is not possible to Access every element in a Queue.

Also, your Approach to use a map sounds good to me. You could implement it as the following:

```
std::list<int> q;
std::map<std::list<int> > previousQueues;

bool queueModified()
{
    //The insert function of a map Returns whether the
    //element was inserted or not.
    bool inserted = previousQueues.insert(q).second;
    return inserted;
}
```

Then you can use it like the following:

```
q.push_back(1);
if(queueModified())
{
    cout<<"Same state"<<endl;
}
```

The only Problem is that you have to call the function after each modification of the Queue.

Answer (score 0):

`std::deque` is the suitable STL container to manipulate the queue. It is a Standard Template library implementation of doubled_ended queue. At anytime to check the size of the queue you can use `std::deque::size()` function. More details are available in this URL http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: this does not seem to answer the question